# How to pass the name of a variable to a custom function from `purrr::map()`?

Tags: r, purrr

I want to have a tibble that contains several nearly identical tibbles. In each nested tibble, one variable's contents are shuffled, the others are unchanged. I want to have N (e.g. 10) versions of each shuffled tibble.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15)
permutation_n <- 10
tbl_names <- names(df)

shuffle_var <- function(data, var) {
  data %>% 
    mutate({{var}} := sample({{var}}))
}

> shuffle_var(df, a)
# A tibble: 5 × 3
      a     b     c
  <int> <int> <int>
1     4     6    11
2     2     7    12
3     1     8    13
4     3     9    14
5     5    10    15
```

`shuffle_var()` works correctly if I use it separately.

But if I use it inside `map()`, it will return a tibble with the original variable unchanged, and a new variable called `.x`

```
result <- 
  crossing(variable = tbl_names,
         index = 1:permutation_n) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(variable, ~shuffle_var(df, .x)),
  )

result %>% slice(1) %>% pull(data) %>% .[[1]]

# A tibble: 5 × 4
      a     b     c .x   
  <int> <int> <int> <chr>
1     1     6    11 a    
2     2     7    12 a    
3     3     8    13 a    
4     4     9    14 a    
5     5    10    15 a
```

`result` should contain 30 rows (variables x versions).
Each nested tibble should have 10 different versions, where the values of one variable are shuffled).

I have found several similar examples in SO but none of them helped in this specific issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with `.data` pronoun inside the function:

1. `.data` is the data that is iterated by `map()`.
2. Now we could use `.data[[var]]` inside the function to refer to the wanted column (`var`), and we can use `map()` to iterate of each nested tibble.

```
shuffle_var <- function(data, var) {
  data %>% 
    mutate({{var}} := sample(.data[[var]]))
}

result <- 
  crossing(variable = tbl_names,
           index = 1:permutation_n) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(variable, ~shuffle_var(df, .x))
  )

result %>% 
  slice(1) %>% pull(data) %>% .[[1]]

      a     b     c    .x
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11     1
2     2     7    12     5
3     3     8    13     3
4     4     9    14     4
5     5    10    15     2
```

Comment: wow, didn't know `.data`. Thanks, it works!

Comment: @TamasNagy Does this give the expected result though? This still creates a new variable `.x` and leaves others unchanged, doesn't it?

Comment: @Aurèle, yes, it does give the correct result in R. The result in this answer incorrectly shows a `.x` named variable. When run in R, the right variables are shuffled, without the extra `.x` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pick`

```
 shuffle_var <- function(data, var) {
  data %>% 
    mutate({{var}} := sample(pick(all_of(var))[[1]]))
}
```

-testing

```
out <- crossing(variable = tbl_names,
           index = 1:permutation_n) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(variable, ~shuffle_var(df, .x))
  )
> out$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 × 4
      a     b     c    .x
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11     3
2     2     7    12     2
3     3     8    13     1
4     4     9    14     5
5     5    10    15     4
```